# dynamic datatable using inputs from an xml

Tags: xml, jsf, jsf-2, datatable

I want to create a nested table using jsf for which i have to take values dynamically. Basically a template jsf which will work for any xml provided. 
XML looks something like this

- node0
- node 1
- node 1.1
- node 1.1.1
- node 1.1.2
- node 2
- node 2.1

each and every node will be a table in jsf. Basically a nested dynamic datatable getting values from an xml. Please help me how to do this

Answer (score 0):

you can programmatically create and populate datatables. BalusC already blogged an article about how to use datatables programmatically. Please see: 
http://balusc.blogspot.com.ar/2006/06/using-datatables.html#PopulateDatatable